# How to display updated localStorage data after page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

2 things I would like to accomplish here:

1. I'm trying to display the new high score after the page is refreshed.
2. The high score resets to 0 after refreshing due to `localStorage.setItem('high_score', 0);` so I'm not sure how to properly set this without resetting it to 0 every time the page is refreshed.

```
        let score = 0;
        var high_score = 0;
        localStorage.setItem('high_score', 0);

        document.getElementById('high_score').innerHTML="HIGH<br>SCORE:<br>" + 
        localStorage['high_score'];

        if (score > parseInt(localStorage.getItem('high_score'), 10)) {
            localStorage.setItem('high_score', score);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could only set the storage item except when you need to update it:

```
// assuming the scores will not be negative
const newHighScore = Math.max(localStorage.high_score, score);
localStorage.high_score = newHighScore;
```

And then when using the storage value, alternate with 0:

```
document.getElementById('high_score').innerHTML="HIGH<br>SCORE:<br>" + 
        (localStorage.high_score || 0)
```

Comment: I've commented out ```localStorage.setItem('high_score', 0);``` but now ```var high_score = 0``` is resetting it to zero. Where would be an appropriate place to put the high_score variable?

Comment: If you want to go this approach, remove the `high_score` variable completely, and only use the storage value. That way, there's a single source of truth, rather than multiple, which could get a bit confusing

Comment: Ok, removed it. When you say storage value, are you telling me to use ```localStorage.setItem('high_score', 0);```? Because this makes the high score say ```[object HTMLDivElement]``` instead of a number.

Comment: I'm referring to the same variable you referenced in the earlier comment - the `var high_score = 0`. Remove that and all references to it entirely and use local storage instead, so there's a single source of truth.

Comment: I just realized I need the variable for my other functions to work properly. My apologies, I can't really delete it. So is there a way to temporarily set it at 0 and then switch to ```localStorage``` after ```high_score``` is greater than 0?

Comment: If you have a lot of references to it, make a function that retrieves the high score instead. `const getHighScore = () => Number(localStorage.high_score)` and then call that function instead of referencing `high_score`.

Comment: Here's a visual representation of my problem: https://codepen.io/chrisluhrsva/pen/RwpoqMG when button D is clicked, score and high score go to 1. Now, when refresh is clicked, the new high score should be displayed instead of being 0.